# zsh terminal in IntelliJ failed to start

Tags: intellij-idea, oh-my-zsh

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-213.7172.25, built on March 15, 2022

[image]

and when I want to open terminal I have an error:

> Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [/bin/zsh, -i] in

and in logs:

> 2022-03-28 09:44:06,301 [  37867]   INFO -
> redIndexChunkConfigurationImpl - Failed to download shared index
> (org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_2_5_5_RELEASE-befd5279b696e187a10626209777efd701945beab4701b442ea4017839f7e7a9-deddd6f123db)
> 2022-03-28 09:44:08,649 [  40215]   INFO -
> hon.packaging.PyPIPackageCache - Loaded 361189 packages from
> /home/baku/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.3/python_packages/pypi-cache.json
> 2022-03-28 09:44:31,041 [  62607]   WARN -
> ctionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater - 207 ms to grab EDT for #update
> (org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner$2)  2022-03-28
> 09:44:31,227 [  62793]   INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner -
> Cannot open Local Terminal  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> Failed to start [/bin/zsh, -i] in /home/xyz/Dev/X     at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:196)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:42)
> at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner.lambda$openSessionInDirectory$4(AbstractTerminalRunner.java:273)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:263)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown reason    at
> com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.execInPty(UnixPtyProcess.java:222)  at
> com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.(UnixPtyProcess.java:62)  at
> com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:146)     at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:183)
> ... 12 more

any ideas how to fix it ? ( ZSH of course works normally when I open terminal )
I use linux mint 20.3, kernel 5.4.0-105-generic

Comment: What is the output of `which zsh`?

Comment: usr/bin/zsh but I tried to use it also in intellij and I have the same error: Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [/usr/bin/zsh, -i]

Comment: but running /bin/zsh -i in my system terminal works fine..

Answer (score 2):

ok I found the solution,my previous install was from software manager, so I removed it and installed via snap:

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

after that switching terminal to zsh works fine.

Comment: holy cow you probably saved me hours! I am working on Pop-OS (debian) and tried to use zsh in Android Studio with the same Error Message 'Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [/bin/zsh, -i]'. After installing Android Studio with snap instead of the Pop!_Shop (I think it used flatpak on Android Studio), it worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's by the *grace* of Flatpak sandbox. IntelliJ, when installed through Gnome Software app, cannot pick up zsh and that imo is a feature! Try configuring IntelliJ's `Preferences > Tools > Terminal > Shell Path` to:

```
flatpak-spawn --host zsh
```

which will invoke `zsh` through Flatpak itself. If you face a `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified` error, define `TERM` on top of your `.zshrc` to make `tput` work in non-interactive terminal environments:

```
[[ -z "$TERM" ]] && export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

The primary Github issue related to this is:
https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate/issues/23